# Create a random number when a new Form is submitted

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-online, microsoft-forms

I have created a Microsoft form for Purchase Order Requests,  when someone submits the form I would like the table on the excel worksheet to create a purchase order number, I am using a combination of sequential and random numbers to create this number.

My problem is that every time a new form is submitted and the worksheet is updated all of the random numbers are recalculated changing the purchase order numbers of other submissions.

Is there a way I can have the formula only calculate when there is a new row added to the table(a new form submission) or any ideas how I can create this number within the Microsoft Form?

I have tried using the Excel online script to create the random number and it's triggered by Power automate flow but I keep getting failed flow runs, and I can't have any failed flow runs at anytime.

Thanks for your help

Comment: no, a formula is live and using randbetween or any random formula will change on evry recompute.  You will need to use officeScripts.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to run the office script every time a new row is added to the table or would I have to use power automate for that?

Comment: You should be able to create event handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events